# How to make selected color the background color in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

How can I make the background color the selected color of a selected row in List View object using vb.net.

I did saw an example with the Ownerdraw set to true - but it messes up the column header. Although I was able to loop through the sub items to make the row selected color the back color

Here's the Code block :

```
  For i = 0 To LV_ProductsEdit.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems.Count - 1
        LV_ProductsEdit.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(i).BackColor = Color.Gold
   Next
```

I have a similar loop that reverts it to the original transparent color when the new item is selected.

Any thoughts.

Thanks

Omer

Comment: the listview automatically uses the system highlight color to mark selected items, are you trying to use a different color?

Comment: Yes,I am trying to use a different color. For example - when the user selects a row in the listview I want that to be with Gold color. It does get Gold color but the user can see once they've the lost focus on the listview. so if the row is selected the highlight would be blue

Comment: cant tell what might be wrong without the code; you also did not add a language tag

Comment: [Edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24719006/edit) code does not format in comments

Comment: by the way the program is working fine and as expected. But just curious how to get the color done without the loop.

Comment: This is an XY question.  Overriding the default selection system color (usually white on blue) requires using ListView.OwnerDraw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not quite sure what the problem is.  You dont need to loop thru SubItems though.  Each item has a `UseItemStyleForSubItems` property which tells the subitems to use the same Font, ForeColor and BackColor as the parent Item.  This defaults to True, so setting the Item backcolor should be enough:

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In myLV.SelectedItems
    lvi.BackColor = Color.Gold
Next
```

The original color is not Transparent, but should be `SystemColors.Window`.

---

You can also reset `HideSelection` to False.  When the LV does not have the focus, the selected items will still be highlighted (grey) which seems to be what you were asking in the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Let me reiterate. I have a products list displayed in ListView. Now what I want is when I select the Row in listview that should be in say Gold color and the color applies to it correctly too. But since the Row is selected the default highlighted color on the row is visible which is Blue, and the moment I shift the focus to other control that Gold is visible

Comment: that is how Windows works.  The **user** has some color associated with `Highlight` which is apparently Blue on your system.  That color is used for LV SelectedItems.  If you want to force it to gold, you will have to subclass teh control and take over the painting.

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix. I will mark that as an answer that was a good tip too :). Just a quick one, any tips on how to subclass ?

Comment: you might want to explore Themes first, or change your approach (subclcassing is a lot of work).  ListView has a `CheckBoxes` property which implements checks by row which would allow a more persistant indicator.  It is not the same as Selected - that would stay - but adds another way to represent what you are after.

Comment: Thanks again @Plutonix. I thought the same too - not to invest too much time specially when the project delivery is close :). I am coming back to code after years, so I have some questions relating to deployment as well and any best practices that you can share would be good. I will post them later.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is change the selection color from blue to something else, here's the code I found to work. First, set ownerdraw to true. Here, my listview is called ListViewQuote.

```
Private Sub ListViewQuote_DrawColumnHeader(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) Handles ListViewQuote.DrawColumnHeader
    e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListViewQuote_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListViewQuote.DrawItem
    If e.Item.Selected = False Then
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListViewQuote_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles ListViewQuote.DrawSubItem
    If e.Item.Selected = True Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(FromArgb(255, 0, 0)), e.Bounds)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, New Font(Me.Font, Nothing), New Point(e.Bounds.Left + 3, e.Bounds.Top + 2), HighlightText)
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
End Sub
```

To change the color from what I have, just change "New SolidBrush(FromArgb(255, 0, 0)" to the brush you want. The forecolor of the text is "HighlightText" which can also be changed to any color.

This works for the Details view of a listview.

---